# What is the "reverse-averaging" technique used in Electroencephalography (EEG)?

Tags: neuroscience, eeg, electrophysiology

Im reading about the Bereitschaftspotential or Readiness-potential "discovery" and I see it was done by "reverse-averaging" the ressults of using EEG to measure certain voltage differences...What is this "reverse-averaging" technique?

Comment: Can you cite the source you refer to?

Comment: @BryanKrause https://worldneurologyonline.com/article/experiments-readiness-action-50th-anniversary-bereitschaftspotential/ "We described a novel method, reverse averaging, for recording brain electrical  activity prior to voluntary movement in humans by noninvasive means and presented the first fundamental results obtained with this method."

Comment: Please [edit] into your question. In any case, if they're proposing a "novel method", seems your best source for the answer is going to be that exact paper, no? What do they say about it?

Comment: Did you read the paragraph starting "It was Hans Kornhuber, who found the solution:"?